# Where is wstool documented?

Tags: ros, wstool, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Taking `.rosinstall` file's format as an example, until I saw [this ticket](https://github.com/vcstools/wstool/issues/23), I didn't know that it can specify `branch` to sync by `version` attribute. `wstool --help` didn't tell me (no wonder). I could find info about it neither on its [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/wstool) nor on the [document page](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosinstall/html/) linked from wiki.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162286/where-is-wstool-documented?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm pretty sure it is not separately documented from `rosinstall`/`rosws`.

Most of the options for `rosws` apply, but unfortunately the `-h` option for it on the command line is probably the best documentation available for it.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`wstool help`  and `wstool help CMD` are relatively complete

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1